# Connect to Sharepoint 2003 in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint, dll, com

I'm creating a WPF application that should list holiday details from a Sharepoint 2003 server. What would be the proper libraries to use? Am I relegated to COM objects or do .NET libraries exist that are compatible with SP 2003?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

a. Using Sharepoint web services

```
Suppose your sharepoint server URL is as follows
https://MyDomain/MySite/default.aspx

Then replace default.aspx with /_vti_bin/lists.asmx to get list of web services expose by sharepoint.
https://MyDomain/MySite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx

This will provide you with list of all operations exposed by service.

You can use GetList to get calendar list and check if you get desired result.
```

b. Uisng Sharepoint object model and Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll (WPF application can run on same server where sharepoint is installed)

Comment: If I use the Sharepoint web services, what libraries would I need to import?

Comment: You do not need any libraries to import. simple add web reference and proxy is generated.